# React router location not triggering update

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have the following code inside a Navbar component:

```
renderAccountButton = user => {
  const path = this.props.location.pathname;
  const regex = new RegExp(/^\/register/);
  if (user.isAuthenticated) {
    return (
      <Button color="inherit" onClick={this.handleLogoutClick}>
        Logout
      </Button>
    );
  } else {
    return (
      <div>
        {!regex.test(path) && path !== "/" ? (
          <Button color="inherit" onClick={this.handleSignUpClick}>
            Sign Up
          </Button>
        ) : null}
        <Button color="inherit" onClick={this.handleLoginClick}>
          Login
        </Button>
      </div>
    );
  }
};
```

The issue is that sometimes when the path is changed, it does not trigger an update. I have this code to check for that:

```
  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("mount");
  }

  componentDidUpdate() {
    console.log("update");
  }
```

It seems that whenever I click a button or link that uses `this.props.history.push("/newpath")`, it doesn't trigger an update (nothing above is logged to the console). So as an example, if I'm at a "/register/user-type" path, and then I click a link to take me to the login page, the Sign Up button (which is gone because I was at the "/register/anything" path) doesn't render because the component is not detecting any changes/updates.

The Navbar component this code resides in is wrapped inside the `withRouter()` wrapper, and its parent is my App component that contains the actual Router. Any ideas as to why this happens? And is there something I could pass to the Navbar component to trigger the update?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**

Here is my Router code that includes the component:

```
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
...rest of imports...

class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      navOpen: false
    };
  }

  toggleDrawer = () => {
    this.setState({
      navOpen: !this.state.navOpen
    });
  };

  handleLinkClick = () => {
    this.setState({ navOpen: false });
  };

  render() {
    const { classes } = this.props;
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
          <Router>
            <div className={classes.app}>
              <Navbar
                toggleDrawer={this.toggleDrawer}
                navOpen={this.state.navOpen}
                handleLinkClick={this.handleLinkClick}
              />
...rest of App...
```

Here is where I've wrapped my Navbar:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, clearCurrentProfile }
)(withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Navbar)));
```

**Edit 2**

I may have found the solution. By wrapping the `connect()` wrapper (from react-redux) in the `withRouter()` wrapper, it seems to fix the issue. I will add this as an answer after I run some more tests. I am curious, however, as to what causes the `connect()` wrapper to negate updates from the `withRouter()` wrapper so any further input would be greatly appreciated. For reference, the last block of code above now looks like this:

```
export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, clearCurrentProfile }
)(withStyles(styles)(Navbar)));
```

Comment: Add router.js code

Comment: Where did you put your `check` code?

Comment: If you're referring to my `console.log("match")` and `console.log("update")` checks, they are right above the `render()` function.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in my question, I was able to resolve the issue by wrapping the entire component, including the redux `connect()` wrapper, in the `withRouter()` wrapper. Do not know why this fixes the issue, but it seems to be resolved now. Below is the before and after edits.

Before:

```
export default connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, clearCurrentProfile }
)(withRouter(withStyles(styles)(Navbar)));
```

After:

```
export default withRouter(connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  { logoutUser, clearCurrentProfile }
)(withStyles(styles)(Navbar)));
```